# Scanning Multiple Nuget Package.config files for vunerabilities

Tags: c#, security, package, nuget

I've a few c# MVC asp.NET projects and have gone through them all and updated a few of the packages to patch the security flaws raised in github through the package manager.

Whilst that's all well and good I'm looking for something 'quick and dirty' where I can supply a list of all my packages.config files and it tell me any that require patching as well as the project / path the package.config came from.

Is there anything out there that could do this?

Comment: The capability to do this appears to have been made part of the recent .NET 8 preview 4 release - you could give it a try and see what happens: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8-preview-4/#nuget-auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities

Comment: The dotnet CLI doesn't support packages.config. Also, unfortunately, in the corresponding version of VS/NuGet.exe, NuGetAudit doesn't yet work for packages.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally do this but with the options being quite limited I've created a small application that in effect does what I want.
I've commited a version that can be found here.
You need to down the files and create the console solution - however should all work.
https://github.com/rhousham/NugetMeta/tree/main
In affect you can pass in a file parameter that has a list of all of your packages.config and it will go and get any  vunerabilities from the Nuget platform.

The solution isn't great - however suits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Jetbrain's Rider is a very nice IDE for .NET development (better than Visual Studio IMHO), and it notifies of known vulnerabilities in referenced Nuget Packages.

I suspect if Jetbrains already have this functionality, Microsoft will be copying it pretty soon anyway, that's usually the case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't yet a way to automate it (for example in a CI pipeline). But in VS, if you "manage NuGet packages for solution" (easy way, right click the solution in Solution Explorer, and select manage nuget packages), the installed tab should tell you (via a warning icon) which packages have any known vulerabilities. Note, you must use a package source which provides vulnerability data, which as far as I know is only https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.  If you're using a different package source tht "upsources" from nuget.org, it might not pass through vulnerability data. You'd need to check with the nuget feed provider (or test with a package with a known vulnerability like newtonsoft.json < 13.0.0)